# Creating connection string of database created on different PC

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to use the database send by my friend. He has created it using *Sql Server Management Studio*. While including the *`.mdf`* file, I am getting an  error message (I have mentioned the error at the end of the answer).
I think it is because of the difference in the connection strings. I am new to .NET so I just changed the name in the connection string,

**From,**

```
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=sheroz;Initial Catalog=FLEXIFORMDB;integrated security=SSPI"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**To,**

```
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=Fahad-PC\Fahad;Initial Catalog=FLEXIFORMDB;integrated security=SSPI"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please help me out to make it work. Thanks in advance.

### Error

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabaseWorker(String name, StringCollection files, String owner, AttachOptions attachOptions)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.AttachDatabase(String name, StringCollection files)

===================================

Unable to open the physical file "D:\FlexiFormWF\FlexiFormWF\FlexiFormDB.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: FAHAD-PC\MSSQL
Error Number: 5120
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something with your permissions. At least, this quote from your error message suggests that:

> Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"